# Почему не работает cURL запрос

Tags: java, spring, curl, java-ee, spring-boot

Я хочу cURL запросом удалить все сообщения которые у меня хранятся в базе данных MySQL, так вот я написал запрос и когда ввожу его в командной строке выводит ошибку. 
Вот мой cURL запрос

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" localhost:8080/api/delete
```

Вот такая ошибка выходит в терминале

```
{"timestamp":"2020-01-08T04:35:00.696+0000","status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","message":"Request method 'GET' not supported","trace":"org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch
```

Вот код

```
@DeleteMapping("/api/delete")
    public String clearBase() {
        messageService.deleteMessages();
        return "Все сообщения были удалены";
    }
}
```

MessageRepostory

```
@Query(value = "DELETE * FROM chatMessages", nativeQuery = true)
    void clearBase();
```

Comment: Посмотрите, что означают аннотации `@Get- @Post- -@Delete` и прочие `...Mapping`. Что они заменяют.

Comment: выложите весь код контроллера, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
curl -X DELETE localhost:8080/api/delete
```